# How do I make sure I get a replacement toilet tank that fits the bowl?

Tags: toilet

Our toilet tank suddenly cracked with no warning--a giant crack from handle to base. Luckily we were home and were able to turn off the water / flush before too much leaked out.

Now I'd like to replace the tank, and save the $500+ a plumber will charge, but I'm concerned there are hidden gotchas to the task I don't know.

(It sounds like it's basically--remove all the water and hardware--unscrew bolts--pull gently...correct me if I'm wrong.)

The real question is, how to get a new tank that (a) fits and (b) isn't going to leak itself. I can't find a model number, but the tank is a Toto from 2002 (according to the stamps inside). Is there some sort of master list of toilets out there? And how do I know which gaskets/washers/etc. to use for the new tank?

Comment: You could take a picture of the toilet and send it to Toto to identify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was about to upvote the answer of @GreyBeardedGeek , because in general trying to find a match will be impossible.  But then I read the word Toto.  Toto is a different case: they have a corporate sustainability principle.  The short answer is: call Toto at 1-888-295-8134.  As for gaskets: one should come with the replacement tank, else is easy to get at any hardware store.  Some PTFE plumbers tape is good also, if the supply line nut is metal.

And check the warranty also, it may apply depending on who you talk to at Toto:

***TOTO warrants its residential faucets, bathroom accessories and cast iron tubs, excluding the acrylic side panel and accessories, (Product) to be free from defects in materials and workmanship during normal use when properly installed and serviced, for the lifetime of the Product from date of purchase.***

The only real gotcha in this job is "don't drop anything".  The tanks are made of ceramic and crack easily (not to mention do a bang up job on toes).

The only real gotcha in the warranty is that it is nominally non-transferable.

Comment: In fact, contacting Toto directly worked--a replacement (the original model is no longer manufactured) is on its way!

Comment: To @Bryce: I upvoted you Outstanding Answer! Phone number to call, what to do if he doesn't get the needed gasket, plus TOTO's warranty: first class information.

Comment: And to bring closure--was able to install it myself with no significant problems. Lots of time with a basin wrench.